# Unable to define non unique index in a table with Innodb

Tags: mysql, database, indexing

I have a table with 4 columns - id(auto incremented), tournament_id, userid, cash.

userid & tournament_id may have duplicate entries but combination of tournament_id and userid is always unique.

So according to my requirement i need to have 2 set of indexes.

1. userid
2. tournament_id, cash

but i am not able to create index with non unique entries as it keeps giving me following error:

```
  "Failed to create index : SQL create unique index `test_index` on `table_name` 
  (`tournament_id`) failed : Duplicate entry"
```

Comment: You actually trying to define unique index. Show your script.

Comment: If that error message isn't clear enough, I'm afraid you're not cut-out to deal with IT at all..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is called a composite primary key.

```
PRIMARY KEY(user_id, tournament_id)
```

It will make sure the combination if `user_id` and `tournament_id` will be unique.

Your table definition should something like.

```
CREATE TABLE user_tournament
{
    user_id INT,
    tournament_id INT,
    cash DECIMAL(5,2), -- should cash be in this table?

    PRIMARY KEY(user_id, tournament_id),
    FOREIGN KEY(user_id) REFERENCES user(id),
    FOREIGN KEY(tournament_id) REFERENCES tournament(id)
} ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Comment: plz let me know if there is a way to declare a non unique index!

Comment: Just declare an `INDEX` or `KEY`. BTW. Your question does not comply with your requirements.

Comment: i just tried it, but its not working! i had used this query **ALTER TABLE vkm_cash_in_hand ADD INDEX (tournament_id, cash)** and it gave me the same error which i had mentioned previously!

Comment: if you want the table then plz share your email id

Comment: Just include the table in your question so everyone can read it.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE user_tournament
(
    id int(11) auto_increment
    user_id INT,
    tournament_id INT,
    cash DECIMAL(5,2),
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    KEY(user_id, tournament_id)
);
```

If you like to have the unique key make the create table

```
CREATE TABLE user_tournament
(
    id int(11) auto_increment
    user_id INT,
    tournament_id INT,
    cash DECIMAL(5,2),
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    UNIQUE KEY(user_id, tournament_id)
);
```

If you are adding index to existing table, use ALTER IGNORE TABLE instead of ALTER TABLE

Comment: This is not logical. `user_tournament` is a table making the association between a `user` and a `tournament`. So it will never be referenced by `id`.